# Creating a synchronous animation for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I tried to be as detailed as general in the title, but it ended up vague anyway. So, I will elaborate here:

I have the following HTML:

```
​<span class="item c1"><!--content--></span>
<span class="item c2"><!--content--></span>
<span class="item c3 c2"><!--content--></span>
<span class="item c1"><!--content--></span>
<span class="item c1 c4"><!--content--></span>​
```

Okay, so the size of the hypothetical `<!--content-->` is always different, which - in this case - means that also the width of the elements will be different.

So, what I need to do is somehow "filter" the content by their classes. Essentially I need to make them disappear and re-appear when the filter is selected.

The way I make them disappear is to set their width to `0px` and the opacity to `0`—this all happens transitionally, using jQuery's `.animate()`.

The moment the DOM loads, I save their "original" widths to a `data-*` attribute:

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('.item').each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = jQuery(e);
        $e.data( 'origWidth', $e.css('width') );
    });

});
```

Now, when they're being displayed again (or re-filtered, if you will) they all get the same width (I know why, but I don't know a way around it):

```
jQuery('.c'+id+'.item').stop().animate({
    'width' : jQuery('.c'+id+'.item').data('origWidth'), 
    'opacity' : 1
});
//NOTE: the [id] in the above snippet is passed by a 
//function and is the category id.
```

So, what my "real" questions is: Is there a way to synchronously iterate through a jQuery array and animate the attributes – or something along those lines.

Thank you!

Comment: `$e.css('width')` replace it with `$e.width()` and `jQuery('.c-'+id+'.item')` vs `jQuery('.c'+id+'.item')` typo?

Comment: Can you set-up an example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just a couple of words.. You do not have remember the width of each element. jQuery's animation can do it for you. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/AkJAm/3/

```
<span class='item'>Some content</span>
<span class='item'>Another content</span>
<span class='item'>And so on</span>

<br />
<a href='#' id='animate'>Click me</a>
```

And js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#animate').click(function(){
        $('.item').animate({width: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'});
        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I was just editing your post to add the dot, but you beat me to it :-) Nice solution!

Comment: Ah, Thanks! I wasn't aware of the `'toggle'` feature.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
jQuery('.item').each(function(i, e) {
    var $e = jQuery(e);
    $e.data( 'origWidth', $e.css('width') );
});
```

should be

```
jQuery('.item').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).data( 'origWidth', jQuery(this).width() );
});
```

What action causes them to re-appear or being filtered?

I think you are missing the duration of the animation..

```
jQuery('.c-'+id+'.item').stop().animate({
    'width' : jQuery('.c'+id+'.item').data('origWidth'), 
    'opacity' : 1
}, 1000);
```

Also `.item` seems redundant, so:

```
jQuery('.c-' + id).stop().animate({
    'width' : jQuery('.c' + id).data('origWidth'), 
    'opacity' : 1
}, 1000);
```

**Update:**

So back to your question:

"*So, what my "real" questions is: Is there a way to synchronously iterate through a jQuery array and animate the attributes – or something along those lines.*"

Do you need to iterate through them?

Does this not work?

```
jQuery('.c-' + id).stop().animate({
    'width' : 'toggle', // courtesy of @Cheery
    'opacity' : 1
});
```

And what about using `slideUp` and `slideDown` or `slideToggle`?

Comment: `I think you are missing the duration of the animation` The default duration is 400 milliseconds, it could be omitted.